# How do I put the Django-Registration-Redux registration form on other pages?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, registration, django-registration

I'm using Django 1.8 and [Django-Registration-Redux 1.2](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration).

I'd like to use a custom Django-Registration-Redux registration form on the landing page.

I have this in `registration_custom/forms.py`:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormTermsOfService, RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistrationFormUniqueEmailAndTOS(RegistrationFormTermsOfService, RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    pass
```

And to use this, my project `urls.py` includes this:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmailAndTOS), name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

There are three views involved for registration out of the box:

**views.py:**

```
class _RequestPassingFormView(FormView)
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView)
```

**backends/default/views.py**

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView as BaseRegistrationView
class RegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView)
```

So I *think* I need any `views` that will contain a registration form to inherit `RegistrationView` from `backends/default/views.py`. Is this correct? And how do I go about specifying my custom form?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1.In your views put:

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView    

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

to change the template used for user registration. [Take a look at the documentation.](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html)

2.In your urls put:

```
from apps.views import MyRegistrationView

url(r'^$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

3.Then, in your landing template you can put the form:

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>Register now!</h1>
  <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

     <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary' type="submit" value="{% trans 'Join' %}" />
  </form>
 {% endblock %}
```